# How do I test reading a file?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing a test for one of my classes which has the following constructor:

```
def initialize(filepath)
    @transactions = [] 
    File.open(filepath).each do |line|
      next if $. == 1
      elements = line.split(/\t/).map { |e| e.strip }
      transaction = Transaction.new(elements[0], Integer(1))
      @transactions << transaction 
    end
end
```

I'd like to test this by using a fake file, not a fixture. So I wrote the following spec:

```
it "should read a file and create transactions" do      
    filepath = "path/to/file"
    mock_file = double(File)

    expect(File).to receive(:open).with(filepath).and_return(mock_file) 
    expect(mock_file).to receive(:each).with(no_args()).and_yield("phrase\tvalue\n").and_yield("yo\t2\n")

    filereader = FileReader.new(filepath)
    filereader.transactions.should_not be_nil
end
```

Unfortunately this fails because I'm relying on `$.` to equal 1 and increment on every line and for some reason that doesn't happen during the test. How can I ensure that it does?

Comment: BTW, chaining `open` and `each` is not the same as passing a block to `open` - the file object in your example will *not* automatically be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables make code hard to test. You could use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
File.open(filepath) do |file|
  file.each_with_index do |line, index|
    next if index == 0 # zero based
    # ...
  end
end
```

But it looks like you're parsing a CSV file with a header line. Therefore I'd use Ruby's [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(filepath, col_sep: "\t", headers: true, converters: :numeric) do |row|
  @transactions << Transaction.new(row['phrase'], row['value'])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use `IO#each_line` together with `Enumerable#each_with_index` which will look like:

```
File.open(filepath).each_line.each_with_index do |line, i|
  next if i == 1
  # …
end
```

Or you can drop the first line, and work with others:

```
File.open(filepath).each_line.drop(1).each do |line|
  # …
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with mocking `File` for each test you can try [FakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) which implements an in memory file system based on StringIO that will clean up automatically after your tests.

This way your test's don't need to change if your implementation changes.

```
require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'

describe "FileReader" do
  include FakeFS::SpecHelpers

  def stub_file file, content
    FileUtils.mkdir_p File.dirname(file)
    File.open( file, 'w' ){|f| f.write( content ); }
  end

  it "should read a file and create transactions" do      
    file_path    = "path/to/file"
    stub_file file_path, "phrase\tvalue\nyo\t2\n"

    filereader = FileReader.new(file_path)
    expect( filereader.transactions ).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

**Be warned:** this is an implementation of most of the file access in Ruby, passing it back onto the original method where possible.  If you are doing anything advanced with files you may start running into bugs in the FakeFS implementation. I got stuck with some binary file byte read/write operations which weren't implemented in FakeFS quite how Ruby implemented them.